# Laravel no input file specified

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am getting the "No input file specified" error when running the app in the browser.
It should provide me with the Laravel home page.

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
- map: laravel6.test
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel6.test/public
```

hosts file

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost

192.168.10.10  laravel6.test[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What URL did you use in the broswer? How do we know that the paths under `/home/vagrant` are correct?

Comment: @jalanb it's C:\Users\my name\Homestead\Code\laravel6.test, the URL I used is https://laravel6.test

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to fix it you need to have your homestead.yaml file settings correct. If you want to know how its done follow Jeffery Way tutorial on homestead 2.0 https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two.

Now to fix "Input not specified" issue you need to ssh into homestead box and type

"serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public/directory" this will generate a serve script for nginx. You will need to do this everytime you switch projects

Comment: I saw that video and pretty much followed it through. I tried vagrant ssh, then 
serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/laravel6.test/public. I refreshed the page but still the same issue